# Transparency with multiply blending

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, color-blending

I'm trying to multiply blend some graphics but can't make it work!!

Here is the code:

```
        blendmultiply = new BlendState();
        blendmultiply.ColorBlendFunction = BlendFunction.Add;
        blendmultiply.ColorSourceBlend = Blend.DestinationColor;
        blendmultiply.ColorDestinationBlend = Blend.SourceColor;

 //BackGround
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null, null, cam.get_transformation(GestionEcran.GraphicsDevice));

          BackGround.Draw(spriteBatch, gameTime, 255);

        spriteBatch.End();

 //Character
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null, null, cam.get_transformation(GestionEcran.GraphicsDevice));

          Character.Draw(spriteBatch, gameTime, 255);

        spriteBatch.End();

 //MULTIPLY PROBLEM
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, blendmultiply, null, null, null, null, cam.get_transformation(GestionEcran.GraphicsDevice));

          multipliedeffecrs.Draw(spriteBatch, gameTime, 255);

        spriteBatch.End();

 //Foreground
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null, null, cam.get_transformation(GestionEcran.GraphicsDevice));

          ForeGround.Draw(spriteBatch, gameTime, 255);

        spriteBatch.End();
```

But it only gives black color on transparent part of my png like this:

[image]

Do you know why? Thanks.

Comment: The neutral element of multiplicative blending is "white", not "transparent". Your blend state does not consider the alpha channel at all.

Comment: Didn't work either, the white lighten the area instead of neutralize the element.

Do you know where i can learn how to control alpha channel in custom blendState? 

Thanks

Comment: Your state essentially means `final = 2 * source * destination`. Set `DestinationBlend` to zero and it should not brighten things up.

Comment: It works!!!!!!!!!!!!! How can i thank you enough?